# Java Application to Query Solr

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have indexed a catalog of documents in Solr. I do not need to add/update, I'm purely looking to create a basic GUI application where the user defines the query by means of a text box and receives results, all within a single Java application.

I know that SolrJ seems to be the right pick, but where do I start? It's all local, I just want to set up a prototype interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking about `solrj`, I assume you are pointing to [embedded Solr Server](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#EmbeddedSolrServer).

You need to create an instance of the Solr Server like one of the following -

```
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://HOST:8983/solr/");
```

OR

```
SolrServer server = new EmbeddedSolrServer();
```

Then you can create an instance of `SolrQuery` and add the query i.e. what the user has entered in the textbox. Query the server and the server would return a list of `SolrDocument`s to you.

To understand `SolrQuery` have a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Reading_Data_from_Solr)

Comment: How can I display the returned SolrDocuments?

Comment: You need to read a little to find out. Get the data from the SolrDocument and display it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've got SolrDocument returning the docs now I just need to map everything out. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome champ. Happy searching. ;)